# Authenticated method in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-authentication

I'm using Laravel 6. I want to generate a new API token for the user each time the user logged in.

Referring to some answers on StackOverflow, there is a method `authenticated` in `LoginController` which is been called just after the user is logged in successfully. I cannot find the `authenticated` method in Laravel 6.

Is there a new way to achieve the same thing in Laravel 6?

Answer (score 0):

As per Laravel Documentation:

> If you need more robust customization of the response returned when a
>   user is authenticated, Laravel provides an empty authenticated(Request
>   $request, $user) method that may be overwritten if desired:

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return response([
        //
    ]);
}
```

Just place the following method inside `app\Http\Controllers\LoginController` (overriding it):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    // stuff to do after user logs in
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Reference:

[Laravel -> Authentication -> Authenticating](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#included-authenticating)